# php file upload to the database by update query

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, image

I am trying to update an upload image to folder using php file upload and could not get the previously occured image in the database. Here is my code,problem is I could not get the previous image in the file upload section from database. Please help.

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']))
                    {
                            echo $_GET['msg'];
                    }
        $id=(isset($_GET['id']))?$_GET['id']:'';
        $val=view_data1_event($id);
        if (isset($_POST["events"])&&isset($_POST["description"])) 
            {
                $id=$_POST["id"]; 
                $title=$_POST["events"];
                $description=$_POST["description"];
                $filetmp=$_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"];
                $filename=$_FILES["images"]["name"];
                $filetype=$_FILES["images"]["type"];
                $filepath= "photo2/".$filename;
                move_uploaded_file( $filetmp,$filepath);
                $update1=update_query($title,$description,$filename,$filepath,$id);


                if($update1)
                    {
                        echo "<script>location.href='hotel1_galery_event.php'</script>";
                    }
            }
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="hotel2_galery_eventedit.php" method="post" class="col-sm-4" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group has-info">
                  <label>Event Related images</label>
                  <input type="file" name="images">
                  <input type="hidden" name="image_name" value="<?php echo $val->image_name?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="image_path" value="<?php echo $val->image_path?>">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                  <span>UPDATE</span>
                  </button> 
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form method is `post` and you are using as `get` in php.

Please replace all `GET` with `POST`

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']))
```

This should be,

```
if(isset($_POST['msg']))
```